# Print and Control arrays in VB2010/2013?

Tags: vb.net, printing, control-array

I have homework that constitudes of creating a loop in Visual Basic (The course is about the 2010 version, however, I've also tested with 2013 and 6.0), that prints (Using the print command) "Loop" 10 times, in a for loop. Pretty simple stuff.

However, I can't get the "print" command to work in Visual Basic 2010/2013. Works fine in VB6. Does the command not exist in newer versions?

The relevant chunk of code is literally:

```
Print "test"
```

VB 2010/2013 adds brackets around "test" and refuses to run it, saying "test" cannot be cast to integer (Saying print is about printing to files, not forms)

VB6 Exectues it fine.

Also, relevant, do control arrays exist in VB10/VB13? My understanding is they were removed, however the second way to do it (In case you don't want to use print) is using a control array.

Comment: I have to print it in an actual form, not in the console.

Comment: if `print in a form` means display something on a form, just place the results in something like a label.  (loop or no loop)

Comment: I am aware that's the proper way to do it. However, I am forced to use either print or a control array.

Comment: [What happened to `Print`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dtfzwyx(v=vs.90).aspx).  
[What happened to control arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxt4418a(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: sounds like the coursebook is very out of date or you are trying to do VB6 homework in VS